# Lemma 5.1.5 from Garth Dales, Introduction to Banach algebra

Tags: normed-spaces, banach-algebras

The problem is from Garth Dales, *Introduction to Banach algebra*, chapter 5 and Lemma 5.1.5

> **Lemma:** Let $(A, \|.\|)$ be a unital Banach algebra, let $a\in A$ and let $\epsilon>0.$ then there is a norm $\newcommand{\vertiii}[1]{{\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert #1 \right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert}}\vertiii{.}$ on $A$ such that $\vertiii.$ is equivalent to $\|.\|,$ $\vertiii{e}=1$  and $\vertiii{a}\leq \nu(a)+\epsilon $ where $$\nu(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|a^n\|^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
>
> **Proof**: If we let $b=\frac {a}{\nu(a)+\epsilon}$ the $S=\{b^n: n\in \mathbb{Z^+}\}$ is bounded. For $c\in A$  let $$p(c)=\sup\{\|sc\|: s\in S\},  \vertiii{c}=\sup\{p(cd): d\in A, p(d)\leq 1\}$$

It is easy to prove that $S$ is bounded but I couldn't  check  $\vertiii{a}\leq \nu(a)+\epsilon $

Any piece of advice would be much appreciated

Comment: Hint: show that the effect of multiplying by $a$ is at most multiplying by $\nu(a)+\epsilon$ on $p$ directly from definition of $p(a)$ (or more appropriately, $p(b)$).

Comment: @user10354138, please explain it a little more